# DownloadManager: BroadcastReceiver not called on a 500 error / WAITING_TO_RETRY

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have setup the DownloadManager to download a file. And the BroadcastReceiver is called when I successfully download a file.

However, when the server returns a 500 response, the BroadcastReceiver is not called. I have tested this a Kitkat emulator and a Jellybean emulator. The result is the same. Here are the logs:

```
09-23 14:29:08.450 16249-12657/android.process.media W/DownloadManager: Aborting request for download 146: Internal Server Error
09-23 14:29:08.490 16249-12657/android.process.media I/DownloadManager: Download 146 finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
```

Perhaps the download is not hitting the BroadcastReceiver as normal, since it's waiting to try the file again.

How can I ensure the BroadcastReceiver is called on a 500 error and when the file has a WAITING_TO_RETRY status?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DownloadManager - understanding ERROR\_HTTP\_DATA\_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782965/downloadmanager-understanding-error-http-data-error)

Comment: @ShubhamChauhan  Goto this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782965/downloadmanager-understanding-error-http-data-error question and try it out.